# Не задается формат даты

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Модель

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

Представление

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control })
```

Результат

[image: Изображение]

Как это исправить?
p.s. Еще хотелось бы поменять сообщение валидатора, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить культуру в web.config

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture ="ru-RU" />
</system.web>
```

атрибуты валидации [Здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/7.3.php)